# Remove audio from video annotation in ActivePresenter

Tags: video-editor

I've been creating screencasts lately (cut with real footage) with ActivePresenter.

ActivePresenter allows one to add "annotations" and they can be in various formats including both audio and video clips. I would like to overlay a video clip onto my screencast, but my issue is, I cannot mute or remove the audio from the video clip in ActivePresenter. When accessing the video's properties, there is a volume slider there but it is disabled.

I can remove the audio using a different tool, and then import into ActivePresenter, but I thought this would be pretty standard functionality. So, the question - is there a way to remove audio from a video annotation in ActivePresenter? The format of the video annotation is mp4 (I'll try with other various formats and see if there are formats which ActivePresenter will provide this as an option).

Comment: Cleaned up a bunch of your meta-justification and added the tag for you.  Yes, this should fit within the bounds of on-topic here.  You don't need to justify yourself.  Not sure if we have anyone familiar with the product, but that doesn't mean it doesn't fit.

Comment: I've gotten dinged on other exchanges before when talking about a specific product, and I couldn't find reference to that being taboo or not on the rules, so I figured I'd pre-justify. Now I know for sure, and thanks for adding the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can remove audio from any video in ActivePresenter. To do that, please follow the [instruction in ActivePresenter's community](http://atomisystems.com/community/4508/how-to-i-cut-sound-out-of-a-video-i-import-into-software):

> You just need to select the video, click Adjust Volume tool on the
>   Timeline, and select Mute checkbox.

Comment: I tried this but it changes the volume audio of the whole project, not only the audio of the selected video. Is there a way to mutate the audio of individual videos?

Comment: Got it now! I was adjusting the audio on the right hand pannel of ActivePresenter, but the correct tool is on the toolbars above the timeline.

Answer (score -1):

Besides acting as a professional Video and Audio Converter, iDealsahre VideoGo is also powerful Audio Remover which can remove audio or audio tracks from all kinds of video files on Mac or Windows.